# Vert.x ConfigRetriever listener how to transfer the change to all Verticle

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I struggle with the ConfigRetriever and his listen function. I want that the new Config is passed to the verticles and they consume it.

```
public class ShredderVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start(){
        ConfigStoreOptions fileStore = new ConfigStoreOptions()
            .setType("file")
            .setOptional(true)
            .setConfig(
                    new JsonObject().put("path","src/main/java/evilPlan.json")
            );

        ConfigRetrieverOptions options = new ConfigRetrieverOptions()
            .addStore(fileStore)
            .setScanPeriod(1000);

        ConfigRetriever retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx,options);

        retriever.getConfig(ar -> {
            if (ar.failed()) {
                // Failed to retrieve the configuration
            } else {
                vertx.deployVerticle("FooFighterVerticle",
                        new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(ar.result())
            }
        });

        retriever.listen(change ->{
            JsonObject previous = change.getPreviousConfiguration();
            // New configuration
            JsonObject changedConf= change.getNewConfiguration();
            eventBus.publish("conf.new",conf);

        });
    }
}
```

At the moment I just undeploy all verticles and redeploy them with the new config. I needed to wait until all verticles are undeployed before i deploy the new ones to avoid collisions.

```
for(String deploymentID : vertx.deploymentIDs()) {
        vertx.undeploy(deploymentID, handler -> {
            if(handler.succeeded()){
                logger.info("Undeployed verticle "  + " ID: " + deploymentID);
                counter++;
                if(counter == deploymentNumber) {
                    deploy(changedConf);
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But this seems to be a bad Solution. I want to delegate it to the deployed verticles. After a small search I found a approach to communicate the change over the eventbus like

at the Configretriever listener

```
eventbus.publish("config.new",changedConf)
```

at the verticles

```
eventbus.consumer("config.new", handler ->{
    config().clear().mergeIn(handler.body());
    //do some stuff
}
```

it seems like a good approach because now all verticles decide on their own how they react on a changed Config.

But now I have the problem that the verticles made teir set up on the old config and its not possible to changes all these setting on the easy way.(like httpserver as example)

I tried it with the

```
this.stop()
```

but it didnt affect on the Verticle
to run

```
this.start()
```

also just double up the process but with the old config.

The attempt to work with a JsonObject and to manipulate it afterwards failed.

Is there a way to solve this problem or is the redeployment the best way to handle a change on the request?

Comment: You can't reconfigure an HttpServer while it's live. However you can close then recreate it. Not sure what you meant with `this.stop()`

Comment: As I know a verticle have a `stop()` function which get called when i undeploy it.
It was a try to undeploy it from its own instance and then redeploy it with the start method.

Comment: No it doesn't work like this. `stop` is called by Vert.x when you undeploy a verticle.

Comment: Ah ok I see, with stop() its possible for me to add some routines to the undeployment. But is it possible to simulate a undeployment from the verticle? i dont wanna iterate thru all ids and undeploy all before I deploy them again.
That the Verticle registrate the change for example over the eventbus and then its restart itself? Or is the only option to explicit change everything or reset it directly?

Comment: `But is it possible to simulate a undeployment from the verticle?`
It's not recommended. Vert.x in general does not do any magic autoupdate. If you need to reconfigure an HTTP server, stop it and recreate it.